# Writing HTML inside echos VS Writing HTML Between PHP tags

Tags: php, html, echo

**In Between PHP Tags**

```
if(condition){

?>

<!-- HTML here -->

<?

}
```

**In Echos**

```
if(condition){

echo "HTML here";

}
```

I use above two methods in my code. But I'm wondering which one is the industry standard and good for performance? Are there any pros and cons of above methods? Which method should I use? and Why?

Since I'm new to PHP I hope you guys will help me out to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Not really "standard", but the second one causes much more headaches due to quoting output. See also: [alternative syntax for control structures](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: It all comes down to preference. Go with what you're comfortable with. Personally speaking I would go for the first method if there is a lot of HTML involved whereas if it's a single line or two of HTML I would go for the second method. Readability is the key here. Performance wise, I think it would be too minute to give any importance to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best industry practice is normally to keep your HTML and your PHP completely seperate (see http://www.smarty.net/ as an example of a templating system)

However, you might find your editor will do nicer syntax highlighting if you don't put your HTML in echos

Answer (score 2):

Personal preference based upon readability. Choose whichever will be easier for someone else reading your code (or you in the future) to understand.

Typically speaking though, if it is a *lot* of HTML you wouldn't want to put it inside a PHP echo, and if it's short you would. Think of the former as a template, and the latter as a method that returns an HTML snippet.